# Как правильно пишется слово «не в терпёшь»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, наречия

Как правильно написать слово *не в терпёшь*?
Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Употребление НЕ со словами во многом зависит от их частеречной принадлежности. Однако во всех правилах есть пометка, указывающая на слитное написание НЕ с лексемами, которые без НЕ не употребляются. Понятно, что слова «***втерпёж***» в нашем языке нет, это объясняет слитное написание слова с НЕ.

Более затруднительным является употребление на конце слова мягкого знака.

Правило: На конце наречий сохраняется буква **Ь** после шипящих: *настеж**ь**, проч**ь**, наотмаш**ь***. Исключения – *уж, замуж, невтерпеж* (в этих трех лексемах после шипящего **Ь** не пишется).

Как видим, слово «***невтерпёж***» относится к исключениям, и на конце мы не будем писать букву мягкий знак.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Как правильно пишется слово «невтерпеж»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/nevterpezh)

Answer (score 2):

Наречие непростое, "многоправильное", употребляется, в основном, в разговорной речи.

• Для начала заглянем в орфографический словарь: [**невтерпёж**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B6).

• Почему "ж", а не "ш"?
Образовано от глагола "терпеть" → "терпё**ж**" (сущ.).
Сравните: крепить — крепёж, галдеть — галдёж.

*Я нырнул и, затаив дыхание, подержался за корягу так долго, сколько **терпежу** хватило* (Анатолий Приставкин. Кукушата или жалобная песнь для успокоения сердца).

• Почему слитно?
Морфемный состав: *не, в* — приставки; *терп* — корень; *ёж* — суффикс.
Наречия, в составе которых есть неиспользуемые в современной речи существительные, пишутся слитно (*невдомёк, насмарку*).
Слова "втерпёж" в языке нет, поэтому пишем слитно.

• Почему "ж" без мягкого знака?
Это особенное слово. На конце наречий после шипящих ("ж" — шипящая) пишется мягкий знак, кроме трех исключений: ***уж, замуж, невтерпёж.***

*Его перебивает один доктор наук, филолог, которому давно уже **невтерпеж**...* (Даниил Гранин. Зубр); *Опять же одиночество чем дальше, тем больше угнетало солдата. Порой становилось **невтерпеж**. Но что делать?* (Василь Быков. Волчья яма).

[Слово «невтерпёж» как пишется правильно?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/nevterpezh-kak-pishetsya.html)